# Is it possible to open below code on PyQt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to add some design via PyQt Designer to below GUI:

```
class Ui_MainWindow ( object ) :
    def setupUi (self, MainWindow) :
        MainWindow.setObjectName ( "MainWindow" )
        MainWindow.resize ( 519, 354 )
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget ( MainWindow )
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName ( "centralwidget" )
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton ( self.centralwidget )
        self.pushButton.setObjectName ( "pushButton" )
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton ( self.centralwidget )
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName ( "pushButton_2" )
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget ( self.centralwidget )
        self.retranslateUi ( MainWindow )
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName ( MainWindow )
```

Is it possible to open this directly on PyQt Designer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27135298/737471  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformbuilder.html